# TypeError: JSON string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

I am currently working on getting data from a json URL. I was able to get the data displayed on my local host and I was able to get the only object I need which was data in `archive[0]`. I am only trying to get the service name, summary and date, but I am getting a

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers.
```

any tips on how I can only get those items? Thank you!

```
return render_template('index.html', data=json.dumps(
    data['archive'][0]['service_name']['date']['summary']))
```

from json data:

```
{
    "archive": [
    {
        "service_name": "AWS Sign-In (N. Virginia)",
        "summary": "[RESOLVED] Increased Latencies for SAML Sign-In",
        "date": "1623264111",
        "status": "1",
        "details": "",
}
```

Comment: Please, post [mre]

Comment: @buran I'm perfectly able to understand this question, could you be a bit more specicfic on what is wrong with this question?

Comment: @The_spider, OP is required to provide [mre] and full traceback they get. We should be able to reproduce the problem, not waste time to figure out what they want to ask. All irrelevant code should be removed - e.g. the render template part, json dump, etc.. In this case there is also problem with formatting - the code and sample data are in one code block.

Comment: @The_spider, They refer to sample data as "from json data". It is unclear whether `data` is JSON string or it is already deserialized. Or maybe it is just some data structure and they refer to it as JSON because they are going to dump some data into JSON. In your answer you **assumed** data is already python dict, but again - it is unclear.

Comment: I think it is quite clear that the data is in dictionary or some data form that supports indexing. No one would try to dump a json string or to index to it with a string. An example is also provided, so it is very unlikely that the object is something else than a dictionary. The formatting is perfectly able to be fixed using an edit and thus is not a good reason for closing the question. With a minimal effort, this question is reproducible as the dictionary is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to add extra indexes after "service_name", as it returns already a string. Dictionaries don't work in such a way that you can get different keys just by adding them after eachother, this would not make sense programatically. You should therefore create a new dictionary with the keys you want.

```py
return render_template('index.html',
   data=json.dumps({
       'service_name': data['archive'][0]['service_name'],
       'date': data['archive'][0]['date'],
       'summary': data['archive'][0]['summary']
   }))
```

If it is not a problem that the "status" and "details" keys also get into the dictionary, you can also pass in the whole dictionary.

```py
return render_template('index.html',
    data=json.dumps(data['archive'][0]))
```

Comment: ahhh I see what you mean... that makes sense. Thank you, for breaking it down that worked out. Appreciate it.